# Oracle pivot for in () all values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a working query using the PIVOT function but I am wondering if I have to define all values I want to see as column headers. Here is what I have:

```
select * from 
(
SELECT ID, product, notebal
from accounts 
where (accounts.effdate = ( Select MAX(EFFDATE) FROM accounts)) 

)
PIVOT
(
SUM(notebal) for product in ('NAID','UAID','SVGS','DRFT')
)

Order by 3 desc
```

There are 28 different products. Do I have to define all 28 in the "for product in()" statement?

Comment: Afraid so. There is a dynamic version but it only generates XML output.